# Injecting CSS dynamically in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I am developing an application in Java Vaadin framework in which I am using its Calendar Add-on. That calendar has some component called "Basic Event" on it. Now I want to color that component on run time by creating a CSS class dynamically on run time. How can I achieve that functionality? Any Help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried and succeeded with the following code.

```
   package com.example.cssinject;

   import org.vaadin.cssinject.CSSInject;

   import com.vaadin.Application;
   import com.vaadin.ui.*;

    public class CssinjectApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() {

    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Cssinject Application");
    final Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
    mainWindow.addComponent(label);

    CSSInject css = new CSSInject();
    css.setValue(".custom-style { color: rgb(100, 200, 0); }");
    mainWindow.addComponent(css);

    label.setStyleName("custom-style");

    setMainWindow(mainWindow);  
}
}
```

Comment: I have used CSSInject Add-on for vaadin 6.7.8.

Answer (score 3):

I have used an addon which was mentioned by Sumit Singh, and the current "native"-way is https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Dynamically%20injecting%20CSS

in brief:

```
          Styles styles = Page.getCurrent().getStyles();
          // inject the new background color
          styles.add(".v-app .v-textarea.text-label { background-color:white; }");
```

Comment: Warning: Will cause a leak if performed multiple times, which is the case in the linked Vaadin example  (see [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17216195/reset-remove-dynamic-styles-on-vaadin-8)).